# swich off others element with the same selectors and switch on the clicked one in jquery

Tags: jquery, click, this, addclass, removeclass

I've a simple list of play button, such as

`<a class="play" rel="video-1"></a>
<a class="play" rel="video-2"></a>`

and when I click to one of these I wish to switch off (remove class 'active') the others and switch on (add class 'active') the clicked one.

I've tried this but it doesn't work properly:

```
$('a.play').live('click', function() { 

    $('a.play').removeClass('active');

    $(this).toggleClass('active');          

});
```

I need ".live()" because buttons are loaded asyncrounously.

I wish to remove class "active" on other elements but clicked one, add class "active" on the clicked one and (this doesn't work properly) on the second click remove class ("active") on this.

Any help will be sincerly apreciated.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "doesn't work properly"? What happens? What do you expect to happen that isn't?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work properly"? Also, `live` is deprecated. If you're using jQuery 1.7+ use `on`. If not, use `delegate`.

Comment: You have to close the `<a>` tags. Tag omission is not permitted at anchors.

Comment: Your HTML is incomplete; if you're *nesting* your `a` tags, this won't work (fix by adding `return false;` to the end of your event hander). However, if you're not... this should work.

Comment: @Matt: my markup is correct, I just forgot to include "</a>" in the answer example, now fixed.

Comment: @RobW my markup is correct, I just forgot to include "</a>" in the answer example, now fixed.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: I wish to remove class "active" on other elements, add class "active" on the clicked one but (and this doesn't work properly) on the second click remove class ("active") on the previosly clicked one. I add this now in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it's removed class after second clicking on link as you want

```
$('a.play').live('click', function() { 


    $(this).toggleClass('active');  
    $('a.play').not(this).removeClass('active');        

});
```

Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TD7Yz/1/

Comment: While it's a readability improvement, logically the two should be the same. The element will never have the 'active' class when `toggleClass()` is called on it because of the previous line, so it should only ever add the class.

Comment: thanks mesiesta, but it's not a solution for me, because I wish to remove class ('active') on second click on the element :)

Comment: thanks mesiesta, this works perfectly for me! thank you so much! I vote for your answer.  You can vote for my question if you believe. Thanks anymore!